# Linux LiveCD distro with multiple kernel versions for rescuing old systems?

Tags: linux, linux-distribution

Is there a Linux LiveCD distribution that has a wide variety of kernels you can choose at boot, including new and very old versions (down to version 2.x if possible), out of the box?

I am a Linux admin looking for a universal live rescue medium for my everyday kit.
More often than I'd like, I have to reinstall bootloaders or do other rescue operations on ancient Linux distros, which means I have to boot off a Linux USB, chroot into the old system and run commands. But on very old systems, if the utilities are compiled for its old kernel, they will not always work in the chroot environment because I'm using the newest Linux kernel on the live USB.

Ideally I do not want to keep dozens of old Linux ISOs for each kernel version so I'd like a single distro with multiple kernel versions. I suppose it would also require a separate userland for each major kernel version so it doesn't run into the same kernel incompatibilities described above, but I don't need anything more than a chroot utility on it.

Is there such a distro, or can I make one without too much effort?